# PowerShell: Code to extract data length and precision from Cobol Copybooks

Tags: powershell, cobol, copybook

=== Problem Statement ===
Code to extract data length in digits (not in bytes) and precision from Cobol Copybooks considering all the different data types for PIC format

Will this code be sufficient to handle all cases of PIC data ? Please let me know if there are other formats ?

=== List of the cases that the code is handling ===

PIC X(n): Extracts the length from format "PIC X(n)" where n is the number of characters.
PIC 9(n): Extracts the length and integer length from format "PIC 9(n)" where n is the number of digits.
PIC 9(n)V9(m): Extracts the length, integer length, and precision from format "PIC 9(n)V9(m)" where n is the number of integer digits and m is the number of decimal digits.
PIC -9(n).99: Extracts the length, integer length, and precision from format "PIC -9(n).99" where n is the number of integer digits.
PIC 9(n).99: Extracts the length, integer length, and precision from format "PIC 9(n).99" where n is the number of integer digits.
PIC -9(n).9(m): Extracts the length, integer length, and precision from format "PIC -9(n).9(m)" where n is the number of integer digits and m is the number of decimal digits.
PIC 9(n).9(m): Extracts the length, integer length, and precision from format "PIC 9(n).9(m)" where n is the number of integer digits and m is the number of decimal digits.
PIC 9(n) OCCURS m TIMES: Extracts the length and integer length from format "PIC 9(n) OCCURS m TIMES" where n is the number of digits and m is the number of times the field occurs.
Simple data types: PIC A, PIC 9: Sets the length to 1 for simple data types.

=== PowerShell Code ===

```
$copybookDataType = "PIC 9(09)V99."
$totalLength = ""
$integerLength = "N/A"
$precision = "N/A"

# 1. Handling format: PIC X(n).
if ($copybookDataType -match "^PIC\s+X\((\d+)\).$") {
    $totalLength = $Matches[1]
}
# 2. Handling format: PIC 9(n).
elseif ($copybookDataType -match "^PIC\s+(\d+)\((\d+)\).$") {
    $totalLength = $Matches[2]
    $integerLength = $Matches[1]
}
# 3. Handling format: PIC 9(09)V99.
elseif ($copybookDataType -match "^PIC\s+9\((\d+)\)V(\d+)\.$") {
    $integerLength = $Matches[1]
    $precision = ($Matches[2] -split "9").Count
    $totalLength = $integerLength + $precision + 1
}
# 4. Handling format: PIC -9(n).
elseif ($copybookDataType -match "^PIC\s+-9\((\d+)\).$") {
    $integerLength = $Matches[1]
    $totalLength = $integerLength + 1
}
# 5. Handling format: PIC 9(n)V9(m).
elseif ($copybookDataType -match "^PIC\s+(\d+)\(\d+V(\d+)\).$") {
    $integerLength = $Matches[1]
    $precision = $Matches[2]
    $totalLength = $integerLength + $precision + 1
}
# 6. Handling format: PIC -9(n).99.
elseif ($copybookDataType -match "^PIC\s+-9\((\d+)\)\.(\d+).$") {
    $integerLength = $Matches[1]
    $precision = ($Matches[2] -split "9").Count
    if ($copybookDataType -match "\.$") {
        $precision -= 1
    }
    $totalLength = $integerLength + $precision + 3
}
# 7. Handling format: PIC 9(n).99.
elseif ($copybookDataType -match "^PIC\s+9\((\d+)\)\.(\d+).$") {
    $integerLength = $Matches[1]
    $precision = ($Matches[2] -split "9").Count
    if ($copybookDataType -match "\.$") {
        $precision -= 1
    }
    $totalLength = $integerLength + $precision + 2
}
# 8. Handling format: PIC -9(n).9(m).
elseif ($copybookDataType -match "^PIC\s+-9\((\d+)\)\.9\((\d+)\).$") {
    $integerLength = $Matches[1]
    $precision = $Matches[2]
    if ($copybookDataType -match "\.$") {
        $precision -= 1
    }
    $totalLength = $integerLength + $precision + 4
}
# 9. Handling format: PIC 9(n).9(m).
elseif ($copybookDataType -match "^PIC\s+9\((\d+)\)\.9\((\d+)\).$") {
    $integerLength = $Matches[1]
    $precision = $Matches[2]
    if ($copybookDataType -match "\.$") {
        $precision -= 1
    }
    $totalLength = $integerLength + $precision + 3
}
# 10. Handling format: PIC 9(n) OCCURS m TIMES.
elseif ($copybookDataType -match "^PIC\s+(\d+)\(\d+\)\s+OCCURS\s+(\d+)\s+TIMES.$") {
    $dataTypeLength = $Matches[1]
    $occursTimes = $Matches[2]
    $totalLength = $dataTypeLength * $occursTimes
    $integerLength = $dataTypeLength
}
# 11. Handling simple data types: PIC A, PIC 9.
elseif ($copybookDataType -match "^PIC\s+(\w+).$") {
    $totalLength = 1
}
# 12. Handling format: PIC .9(n).
elseif ($copybookDataType -match "^PIC\s+\.9\((\d+)\).$") {
    $precision = $Matches[1]
    $totalLength = $precision + 1
}
# 13. Handling format: PIC -.9(n).
elseif ($copybookDataType -match "^PIC\s+-\.9\((\d+)\).$") {
    $precision = $Matches[1]
    $totalLength = $precision + 2
}

Write-Host "Total Length: $totalLength"
Write-Host "Integer Length: $integerLength"
Write-Host "Precision: $precision"
```

Comment: There's COMP (binary), COMP-3 (packed decimal), and more rarely COMP-1 and COMP-2 (floating point).  The letter S (sign) is also used with numeric fields.  There's also DISPLAY format, most commonly used for output formats, which include the characters Z, comma, decimal point, and a plus or minus sign.  I think it might be easier to parse the picture than have a dozen different regular expressions.

Comment: This actually is a good question in general - but it doesn't match the Q+A style of stackoverflow... please the the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).<

Comment: In theory you could have additional clauses before the ´OCCURS` (like `INDEXED BY`).
As Gilbert pointed out, you could have a `USAGE`  in there (which of course will change the resulting length). You also could have edited fields (their size is easy to calculate, but you'd need to parse that before).

Comment: You might be able to handle the cases typically used in your organisation, but you are far from handling all cases of valid COBOL: `PIC` could also be `PICTURE`, there might be an optional `IS` after the `PIC`, `OCCURS` can not only be after `9(n)` but after any of the cases before and tons of other valid combinations. So I side with Simon Sobisch:  let a COBOL-compiler do the parsing and analyze the results (compile-listing, debug-data etc).

Comment: If you say "data length", are you referring to the length in digits or to the length in bytes?

Comment: There's also COMP-4 (binary).  Concur with @GilbertLeBlanc.  Unless you're planning to (re)write a COBOL compiler, best to leave that part to the long-existant working code.

Comment: @not2savvy in digits only

Comment: Then the code looks okay, provided the format is always `PIC`.

Answer (score 1):

Question: Will this code be sufficient to handle all cases of PIC data?
Answer: No, for some of the reasons (mostly about formats) see the comments.

The main issue is that the match won't be done correctly according to COBOL rules, because you at least need to add records as well as consider line breaks and comments anywhere; in theory also word-continuation (VERY seldom used), conditional compilation (more often used), `COPY REPLACING` / `REPLACE` and use of constants that are possibly defined outside of the copybook or even with the compile options specified.
Also: for some `USAGE`s different compilers will use different sizes (and `SYNCHRONIZED` may also change the size of the records due to padding, also different per compiler/environment/options).

Conclusion: while you can parse something in powershell - it likely *should not* be a COBOL copybook.
Either gets much more complicated as you need to "parse COBOL" (the *whole* compilation unit, not only a single copybook) and be compiler/environment specific or will be usable only for "simple" inputs.

It would be most reasonable to put the compilation unit to a COBOL compiler that generates a symbol listing (most compilers have an option for that and can also syntax-check only), then parse that symbol listing (which includes the *actual lengths used*) with powershell (can also be done using pipes, no temporary files needed).

As an example: with GnuCOBOL that would be something like `cobc $yourflags_like_dialect_and_copybook_directories -fsyntax-only -frelax-syntax -w -t sym.lst --tlines=0 -fno-tsource -ftsymbols source.cob` (use `-` as output name instead of `sym.lst` if you want the result to be on stdout).