# Elicit the actual variable stored in a string in COBOL

Tags: cobol

I have a variable length string which holds another variable. For example this string is like "MYVAR-1". I want to elicit inner variable and compute its length. Note this inner variable can be both numeric and alphanumeric. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: [INSPECT TALLYING](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/cobol-zos/6.2?topic=statements-inspect-statement)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot access a variable from a name *contained in a variable* in most programming languages.

To solve this you'll create a lookup table, commonly as if-else-if or with a bit better performance with two nested constructs (one with the length of the name, another one with the names).

**In any case you need to do a *specific* lookup for each of the possible names.**

In COBOL you commonly would use `EVALUATE`, together with the `LENGTH OF` register (for max. length) or `FUNCTION LENGTH (FUNCTION TRIM (var)` as follows:

```
EVALUATE var-name
   *> example for storage-length
   WHEN "MYVAR-1"  MOVE LENGTH OF MYVAR-1 TO var-length
   WHEN "MYVAR-2"  MOVE LENGTH OF MYVAR-2 TO var-length

   *> example for "stored length" - you'd only use one for the whole program
   WHEN "MYVAR-4"  MOVE FUNCTION LENGTH (FUNCTION TRIM (MYVAR-4, TRAILING) TO var-length

   *> example for "stored length" - shortcut available in GnuCOBOL (extension)
   WHEN "MYVAR-5"  MOVE FUNCTION STORED-CHAR-LENGTH (MYVAR-4) TO var-length

   *> more cases here...
   WHEN OTHER      DISPLAY 'var-name unknown: ' var-name
                   MOVE 0                 TO var-length
END-EVALUATE
```

If you just want to get the storage-length, do the query often and/ore have many entries in it, then it would be useful to just define a table in `WORKING-STORAGE` that has name and length in there and use a `SEARCH ALL` on that table.

Comment: It seems I didn't explain the question properly. MYVAR-1 can be something like " Name        pic x(90)" or "value       pic x(140). I want to grab 90 or 140 or etc.

Comment: That's a completely different question as the content of the string is not "MYVAR-1" as given as example.
What you want is to parse the length, if all are `x(something)` then this is easy (just check for the first `(` then use `FUNCTION  NUMVAL` with anything until `)`) - but `PICTURE` clauses can be much more complicated - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76699017